# pod2html: Linking to Other Files

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I have a bunch of PODs spread over multiple Perl script files. I want to write a *landing page* for all these PODs using another `.pod` file.

Say, in the folder `/my/root/sub_folder/` I have a script file `FirstScript.pl` with the following POD.

```
=head1 DESCRIPTION

This is the description

=cut
```

In the `TOC.pod` file, I'm trying to link to that section as follows.

```
=over 4

=item L<Link Text|FirstScript/"DESCRIPTION">

=cut
```

When I run:

```
pod2html --podroot=/my/root --podpath=sub_folder --infile=TOC.pod
    --outfile=TOC.html
```

I get get the error:

```
pod2html: TOC.pod: cannot resolve L<Link Text|FirstScript/"DESCRIPTION">
    in paragraph X.
```

Link is resolved if I add the file extension (.pl) to the `name` part of the `L<>` code, but then the resulting URL is of the form "**.pl**.html", which is not how I want the individual outfiles to be like.

What is wrong here? Am I using the `podroot` and `podpath` in a way that was not meant to be used?

Answer (score 5):

You want to use [Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch](http://metacpan.org/module/Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch), it will generate a TOC for you, and it will create and link `FirstScript.html` correctly

```
perl -MPod::Simple::HTMLBatch -e Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch::go perl_files_in_sub_folder html_out_folder
```

- Pod::Simple::HTMLBatch - convert several Pod files to several HTML files
- Pod::ProjectDocs / pod2projdocs - ganerates CPAN like project documents from pod.
- Pod::POM::Web - HTML Perldoc server
- Pod::HtmlTree - Create a hierarchy of HTML documents from your module's PMs.
- and honorable mention unixonly http://perl.overmeer.net/oodoc/

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite the answer I'm looking for. Rather than auto generating a TOC alone, I want to be able to create these links in a bigger document. I'm trying to use POD to write the user manual of a tool and in that, I need to link to various sections of POD spread over many files.

Comment: Sure it is :) and its much simpler than pod2html, it does what you want out of the box, just try it

Answer (score 0):

pod2html needs the parameter --htmldir=...
That's all. Here is my script:
https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=55079

Comment: Please, write the code into the answer, don't use a link to share it.